# whitelist not working ionic with crosswalk

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

I created a working app using ionic. there was no problem with fetching data from my site and everything was good.

I then went to add crosswalk to it and now i get the error when i run it on my android phone:

```
W/XWalkCordovaResourceClient():URL blocked by whitelist: http://example.com/api/
```

In the top level config.xml i have tried each of the following (not all 3 at once) and reran it (ionic run android) with the same results:

```
  <access origin="*"/>
  <access origin="http://www.example.com/*"/>
  <access origin="http://www.example.com"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

running 'ionic info' i get:

```
OS: Max OS Yosemite
Nodoe Version: v0.10.36
Cordova CLI: 4.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.3.19
Xcode version: Xcode 6.2 Build Version 6C121e
ios-sim version: 3.1.1.
```

As a separate but possible related question, after installing crosswalk running the app on an android emulator has stopped working also - after building successfully it just says 'the app has stopped'

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I figured it out! The problem is that in the latest Cordova, they've split out the whitelist functionality into its own plugin.

Simply run `ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git`
and you're good!

Comment: thanks. I added that but can't figure out what the CSP should be for it to work. right now i have: `script-src 'self 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self' http://www.example.com` and i still get those URL blocked by whitelist messages

Comment: You don't have to have CSP for it to work. Just remove the line and it'll complain in the logs but everything should work.

Comment: thanks! in the end i had to upgrade from cordova-android 3.7 to 4.0, then install the plugin and ignore the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems getting tiles from openstreetmaps and google maps api and i solved it by followed the answer from this thread http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/crosswalk-whitelist/20329.

Basically the workaround is to go to
""\platforms\android\src\org\crosswalk\engine\XWalkCordovaResourceClient.java" 
line 204, comment the return out and rebuild the app.

Its not a smooth solution but it solves my problem for now.

In regards to your other question the steps i would suggest is to first :  Emulate using Genymotion. If that doesnt work i would try to remove and re-add Android.

Hope it helps.